# How to remove substring from list in python

Tags: python, string, list

Assume that we have list like this  `l = ['ab','bc','cd','ef','abcd','efi']`  . In that `l[0] = 'ab'` and `l[1] = bc` are in `l[4] = 'abcd'` similarly `l[3] = 'ef'` also located in `l[5] = 'efi'`. so i  want to remove `l[0],l[1],l[3]`and need to return `l = ['cd','abcd','efi']`.Can any one solve this problem using python

Comment: it's not  clear , what do you want to remove exactly ? , and what did you try ?

Comment: In your example, do you want to remove `l[0]`, `l[1]`, and `l[3]`? Or do you want to remove `l[4]` and `l[5]`? Or do you want to do something else entirely?

Comment: Keep in mind that `str` values are immutable. You can't remove a substring from a string; you can only replace the string with a *new* string that does not contain the substring.

Comment: how efficient you need it to be? would an O(n2) brute force algorithm suffice or you need something smarter? How big is your list and your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of a brute-force approach, but for each element, you can go over the list and check if it's contained in any other element:

```py
result = [x for x  in l if not any(x != y and x in y for y in l)]
```